# Failing to base64 encode json string to use as input in github action

Tags: json, github, google-cloud-platform, base64, github-actions

My SA key is stored as json

However the following example using an action that requires the SA key in `base64` encoded format, fails

```yaml
    - name: base64 encode the staging gcr sa
      id: base64-staging-gcr
      shell: bash
      run:
        echo "::set-output name=STAGING_GCR_SA_BASE64::$(echo '${{ secrets.STAGING_GCR_SA }}' | python -m base64 -e)"

    - name: build and push to staging gcr
      id: stg_img_build
      uses: RafikFarhad/push-to-gcr-github-action@v4
      with:
        gcloud_service_key: ${{ steps.base64-staging-gcr.outputs.STAGING_GCR_SA_BASE64 }}
        registry: gcr.io
        project_id: $STAGING_GCR_PROJECT
        image_name: ${{ github.event.inputs.image_name }}
        image_tag:  ${{ github.event.inputs.image_tag }}
```

as follows:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://gcr.io/v2/": unknown: Unable to parse json key.
```

Any ideas if I am doing something wrong in the encoding?

Comment: Echo the value of **STAGING_GCR_SA_BASE64**. Copy and paste to your local system and then manually base64 decode. Verify that the JSON was not corrupted.

Comment: The echo step obfuscates the value for some reason `Run echo "ewogICJ0***CiAgInByb2plY3RfaWQiOiAibm90ZWQtaGFu"
  echo "ewogICJ0***CiAgInByb2plY3RfaWQiOiAibm90ZWQtaGFu"`

Comment: Save it to a file (artifact) and then download it manually.

Comment: I did and thanks for the tip. It seems like the contents of the key are partially (?) encoded `[13/06/22 2:11:54] ➜  Desktop echo ewogICJ0eXBlIjogInNlcnZpY2VfYWNjb3VudCIsCiAgInByb2plY3RfaWQiOiAibm90ZWQtaGFu | base64 --decode
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "noted-han%  `

Comment: I have no idea why this happens

Comment: Is that the full base64 encoded string that you are seeing? Is there some string after iAibm90ZWQtaGFu?

Comment: Yes it is the full, but it is not the entire json that has been encoded